# When is the full version (4 mins) ending song of the anime god eater releasing?

Tags: god-eater

I have been searching in different websites but I could only find the short version of kouhaichi.

Comment: To the people that are flagging and voting for this as requesting illegal copy righted material. The question here seems to be when it is realising, not for download links, please refer to the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Full anime ED, OP and Soundtracks is always first come in **Bonus CD inside Blu-ray Collector Edition**. So, if you want a full version of ending song for example, you need to wait for the release of the Blu-rays.

*God Eater* just finished airing recently, I don't know the Bonus CD will be packed inside which volume of the Blu-ray. An anime with 13 episodes like *God Eater* is usually sold separately with 7 volumes, while Vol. 6 is released just a week ago, Vol. 7 will be released on *April 21th*. Maybe a week or so after the release of all volumes, some websites might provide contents in the Bonus CD on their site, not sure whether it's legit or not.

Comment: This is mostly untrue. It is far more common for full-length OPs/EDs to be released separately as part of a single. For example, the OP for God Eater ("Feed A") was released on an OLDCODEX album back in August. The situation with God Eater's ED "Kouhai Chi" is unusual in this respect. (While it is common for soundtracks to be released as bonus discs with BDs, it is an overstatement to claim that this is "always" the case.)

Comment: Side note: the [God Eater website](http://anime.godeater.jp/blu-ray/vol7.php) says that volume 7 will only include the TV-size version of "Kouhai Chi", and explicitly states that the full-length version will not be included.